# Open PDF file from web browser with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I need to open pdf document. So far I have web application which has pdf file path in hyperlink so when I click on that link it has to open that file in web browser or default pdf application like Acrobat. Here is link
 `<div class="col-md-7 value"><a href="c:/JobData/4861.pdf" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> View </a> </dv>`
 When I tried to open it firefox says "The address wasn’t understood". Same file I can open in firefox by right click on file and selecting "open with" option. 
I also tried to open it with php code but there is message that "PDF document might not displayed correctly" and it didn't show content at all. Here is php code

```
<?php
$file = 'c:/JobData/';
$filename = '4861.pdf'; 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
?>
```

Does someone has solution for this? Thanks for viewing this question.

Comment: Why is javascript tagged? You are looking for an implementation in php correct?

Comment: ""c:/" is the local computer a valid url would fix this

Comment: You can see in link that it is valid file path, but when I open that file manually there is "file:///" added before C: and I tried by adding that file slash as well and its not working.

Comment: if its showing file: are you running this on a web-server or just loading the page directly in the browser?

Comment: running WAMP - local server, it is not showing file but when I manually open file it add file in front of C drive letter

Comment: the file has to be inside the web root, which is unlikely to be `C:\` create a directory for the pdf inside the web root and reference it there.

Comment: so is it like to view pdf file I copy it from C://pdf_directory to pdfdirectory under www or any subfolder of my working directory? I can do this but when viewing is complete than I need to delete file otherwise it just keep adding and taking space for nothing. There must be better solution.

Comment: its taking up the same amount of space currently, i dont understand the issue

Comment: Original file has to be in particular folder which I can't change so for only viewing purpose I need to copy that file in localhost and while viewing if someone changed it, it's hard to figured out that changes and copy that changed file to its original location and delete file from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is somehow related to the url. If I open some file in my computer via my browser (Opera and Microsoft Edge) the url would look something like this:

```
file:///C:/xxx/xxx.pdf
```

Maybe simply put c:/... will not work.

Another problem with your php code is that $file is just a path , not a file. See more example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Keep in mind that when you use this code in real production , you cannot redirect user to your own drive etc "c:/" because it would mean to use user "c" drive instead.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I supplied filename in second header line. So all together its valid file path but its not working so obviously there is something wrong. I am going to check your suggestion, Thanks